# How to add XML attribute values of specific elements incrementally based on the attribute values of their parent elements?

Tags: python, xml, xslt

I have a following ALTO-XML input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="remove_tags.xsl"?>
<alto xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v2#"
      xmlns:page="http://schema.primaresearch.org/PAGE/gts/pagecontent/2013-07-15"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v2# http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/alto.xsd">
         <root>
             ...
               <TextLine ID="tl_1"
                         BASELINE="1118"
                         HEIGHT="166"
                         WIDTH="3877"
                         VPOS="952"
                         HPOS="1091">
                  <String ID=""
                  HEIGHT="166"
                          WIDTH="468"
                          VPOS="952"
                          HPOS="1024"
                          CONTENT="34."/>
                  <SP HEIGHT="166" WIDTH="67" VPOS="952" HPOS="1492"/>
                  <String ID=""
                  HEIGHT="166"
                          WIDTH="1337"
                          VPOS="952"
                          HPOS="1292"
                          CONTENT="&lt;b&gt;BONAPARTE&lt;/b&gt;"/>
                  <SP HEIGHT="166" WIDTH="67" VPOS="952" HPOS="2628"/>/>
               </TextLine>
            ...
         </root>
```

I need to add the `ID` attribute values of the elements `String` incrementally based on the corresponding `ID` attribute values of their parent elements `TextLine`.

Desired output:

```
      <root>
         ...
           <TextLine ID="tl_1"
                     BASELINE="1118"
                     HEIGHT="166"
                     WIDTH="3877"
                     VPOS="952"
                     HPOS="1091">
              <String ID="tl_1_1"
              HEIGHT="166"
                      WIDTH="468"
                      VPOS="952"
                      HPOS="1024"
                      CONTENT="34."/>
              <SP HEIGHT="166" WIDTH="67" VPOS="952" HPOS="1492"/>
              <String ID="tl_1_2"
              HEIGHT="166"
                      WIDTH="1337"
                      VPOS="952"
                      HPOS="1292"
                      CONTENT="&lt;b&gt;BONAPARTE&lt;/b&gt;"/>
              <SP HEIGHT="166" WIDTH="67" VPOS="952" HPOS="2628"/>/>
           </TextLine>
        ...

      </root>
```

The current XSLT scheme, based on [this](https://www.oxygenxml.com/archives/xsl-list/200708/msg00253.html) one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
        version="2.0"
        xpath-default-namespace="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v2#">

        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>



        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
                <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="String[@ID]">
                <xsl:variable name="vInum">
                        <xsl:number count="String[@ID]"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <String ID="{concat(TextLine[@ID],'_',$vInum)}">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select=
                                "@*[not(name()='ID')]
                                |
                                node()
                                "
                        />
                </String>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

generates the following output, where the `ID` attribute values' indices of the child elements are added incrementally, but I cannot manage to concatenate those indices with the `ID` of the parent elements, as proposed by @Martin Honnen.

Where am I wrong?

```
               <TextLine ID="tl_1"
                         BASELINE="1118"
                         HEIGHT="166"
                         WIDTH="3877"
                         VPOS="952"
                         HPOS="1091">
                  <String xmlns=""
                          ID="_1" -----------> desired output "tl_1_1"
                          HEIGHT="166"
                          WIDTH="468"
                          VPOS="952"
                          HPOS="1024"
                          CONTENT="34."/>
                  <SP HEIGHT="166" WIDTH="67" VPOS="952" HPOS="1492"/>
                  <String xmlns=""
                          ID="_2" -----------> desired output "tl_1_2"
                          HEIGHT="166"
                          WIDTH="1337"
                          VPOS="952"
                          HPOS="1292"
                          CONTENT="&lt;b&gt;BONAPARTE&lt;/b&gt;"/>
                  <SP HEIGHT="166" WIDTH="67" VPOS="952" HPOS="2628"/>
               </TextLine>
```

Comment: I have added a minimal working example and one XSLT transformation that nearly worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<String ID="{concat(TextLine[@ID],'_',$vInum)}">
```

you should be using:

```
<String ID="{concat(../@ID,'_',$vInum)}">
```

However, that creates a new `String` element in no-namespace. To modify the existing `String` element, I would suggest you do:

```
<xsl:template match="String">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="ID">
            <xsl:value-of select="../@ID"/>
            <xsl:number format="_0"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except @ID | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Note that the above is XSLT 2.0 syntax (as is the `xpath-default-namespace` you are using). I am not sure you get that with python.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT, use `xsl:number` to  compute the index number for the String elements and concat the id of the parent element.